# Kubernetes does not start after restart system (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I installed K8s on my two Ubuntus in VirtualBox (Master and Node01). After installation (I proceeded according K8s doc site) I typed `kubectl get nodes` and got bot servers in status *Ready*. But after restart systems I got this:

```
# kubectl get nodes 
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the 
right host or port?
```

I checked kubelet service and it is running:

```
# systemctl status kubelet
kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent 
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d 
           └─10-kubeadm.conf 
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-04-24 10:01:51 CEST; 15min ago 
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/ 
Main PID: 13128 (kubelet) 
    Tasks: 21 
   Memory: 48.2M 
      CPU: 58.014s 
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service 
           ├─13128 /usr/bin/kubelet --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --require-kubeconfig=true --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local 
           └─13164 journalctl -k -f 

Apr 24 10:16:40 master kubelet[13128]: I0424 10:16:40.204156   13128 kuberuntime_manager.go:752] Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=weave pod=weave-net-5qgvz_kube-system(4b7bb2f0-2691-11e7-bfb6-080027229776) 
Apr 24 10:16:40 master kubelet[13128]: E0424 10:16:40.204694   13128 pod_workers.go:182] Error syncing pod 4b7bb2f0-2691-11e7-bfb6-080027229776 ("weave-net-5qgvz_kube-system(4b7bb2f0-2691-11e7-bfb6-080027229776)"), skipping: fail 
Apr 24 10:16:42 master kubelet[13128]: I0424 10:16:42.972302   13128 operation_generator.go:597] MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "kubernetes.io/secret/2b59d0d9-2692-11e7-bfb6-080027229776-default-token-h3v7c" (spec.Name: " 
Apr 24 10:16:48 master kubelet[13128]: I0424 10:16:48.949731   13128 operation_generator.go:597] MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "kubernetes.io/secret/2bb42bc1-2692-11e7-bfb6-080027229776-default-token-h3v7c" (spec.Name: " 
Apr 24 10:16:51 master kubelet[13128]: I0424 10:16:51.978663   13128 operation_generator.go:597] MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "kubernetes.io/secret/2b023c31-2692-11e7-bfb6-080027229776-default-token-h3v7c" (spec.Name: " 
Apr 24 10:16:52 master kubelet[13128]: I0424 10:16:52.909589   13128 operation_generator.go:597] MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "kubernetes.io/secret/4b7bb2f0-2691-11e7-bfb6-080027229776-default-token-gslqd" (spec.Name: " 
Apr 24 10:16:53 master kubelet[13128]: I0424 10:16:53.186057   13128 kuberuntime_manager.go:458] Container {Name:weave Image:weaveworks/weave-kube:1.9.4 Command:[/home/weave/launch.sh] Args:[] WorkingDir: Ports:[] EnvFrom:[] Env: 
Apr 24 10:16:53 master kubelet[13128]: I0424 10:16:53.188091   13128 kuberuntime_manager.go:742] checking backoff for container "weave" in pod "weave-net-5qgvz_kube-system(4b7bb2f0-2691-11e7-bfb6-080027229776)" 
Apr 24 10:16:53 master kubelet[13128]: I0424 10:16:53.188717   13128 kuberuntime_manager.go:752] Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=weave pod=weave-net-5qgvz_kube-system(4b7bb2f0-2691-11e7-bfb6-080027229776) 
Apr 24 10:16:53 master kubelet[13128]: E0424 10:16:53.189136   13128 pod_workers.go:182] Error syncing pod 4b7bb2f0-2691-11e7-bfb6-080027229776 ("weave-net-5qgvz_kube-system(4b7bb2f0-2691-11e7-bfb6-080027229776)"), skipping: fail
```

Here is systemd log file with restarted kubelet: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3EINM-iyF06SXNvUWRoQWZzS2M).

... I'm not sure what I missed in doc or what happend with kubelet. Can I ask you for help? :]

•        Ubuntu version

```
cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu" 
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)" 
ID=ubuntu 
ID_LIKE=debian 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS" 
VERSION_ID="16.04" 
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/" 
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/" 
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" 
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial 
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

•        Kernel

```
# uname -a 
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

•        Kubectl version

```
# kubectl version 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.1", GitCommit:"b0b7a323cc5a4a2019b2e9520c21c7830b7f708e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-03T20:44:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} 
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T16:24:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

•        Kubeadm version

```
# kubeadm version 
kubeadm version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.1", GitCommit:"b0b7a323cc5a4a2019b2e9520c21c7830b7f708e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-03T20:33:27Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

•        Kubelet version

```
# kubelet --version 
Kubernetes v1.6.1
```

•        Docker version

```
# docker version 
Client: 
Version:      1.11.2 
API version:  1.23 
Go version:   go1.5.4 
Git commit:   b9f10c9 
Built:        Wed Jun  1 22:00:43 2016 
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64 

Server: 
Version:      1.11.2 
API version:  1.23 
Go version:   go1.5.4 
Git commit:   b9f10c9 
Built:        Wed Jun  1 22:00:43 2016 
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: You should get some context in the kube-api-server log as to why it failed to start.

Comment: @Anirudh Ramanathan - now I'm analyzing systemd log. But it has around 200 lines. Where is it possible to put it?

Comment: Log is added to question.

Comment: kubelet log? Or other kubernetes logs?

Comment: In fact I didn't find any log files for Kubelet or K8s. All what I have is just in journald. I found this on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/26726): _There is no plan to bring back /var/log/kubelet.log. All logs (even for other /var/log/kube*.log files in future) will be available in journald._

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43633562/4742108

Comment: @Velkan - This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616227/installing-kubernetes-on-virtual-box-with-ubuntu/43633562#43633562) I already found and had checked. I checked now it again and found out where was problem. I had in _/etc/environment_ file this line: `export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf`. But variable `$HOME` in this case is not known. So variable is still `$HOME/admin.conf` without resolved `$HOME`. After I moved `export` to _.zprofile_  it is working. What is great. Thank you for your kick to right place, because it was stupid mistake. ;] :]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a bad exported variable `KUBECONFIG` which is needed by kubelet (history details are in a comment under question).

To `~/.zprofile` I saved `KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf` which solved my problem.

After reloading ENV variables is kubelet working:

```sh
# kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS     AGE       VERSION
master    Ready      5d        v1.6.1
node01    NotReady   5d        v1.6.1
```

Comment: `~/.zprofile` or `~/.bashrc` everybody does not have zsh ;)

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem with kubernetes 1.12.3 and ubuntu 16.04.05. I then looked at the kubernetes log by running the command

`$ journalctl -u kubelet`

and then in the log i saw that k8s was complaining (exiting with status 255) about swap being on.

So i then turned swap off by running

`$ swapoff -a`

Then i edited fstab and commented out the entry for swap

```
$ vi /etc/fstab
#comment out line with swap
```

and then rebooting the system.
After the system came back up, i verified that swap was disabled by running

`$ free -m`

and checking whether the row for swap has 0. It did.

Then i verified that kubeapi service had successfully started by executing

`$ systemctl status kubelet`

It has successfully started. I verified by also re-checking journalctl logs. Did not see swap error this time.

I verified k8s node status by running

`$ kubectl get nodes`

which was now working and showing expected output.

NOTE: I had KUBECONFIG set in my .bash_profile file as well, previously.

```
root@k8s-master:~# cat .bash_profile
export KUBECONFIG="/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
```

Comment: This. For bootstrapping containers I used this little one-liner to disable swap in fstab: `sudo sed -i 's|^/swap.img|#/swap.img|g' /etc/fstab`

Answer (score 2):

As the comment there, you really need check whether `apiserver` is started, because `kubectl` will talk to `apiserver`. While from you description and version of kubeadm, I believe this is a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616227/installing-kubernetes-on-virtual-box-with-ubuntu) I just answered, so I just copy the answer to here.

---

In current version of `kubeadm`(v1.6.1), insecure port of ApiServer is abandoned by default, you can verify this by checking api-server yaml file in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`, there is kube-apiserver parameter `--insecure-port=0`.

You can

- Correct this in a running cluster:

  ```
  $ mv kube-apiserver.yaml ../kube-apiserver.yaml
  // edit ../kube-apiserver.yaml to remove --insecure-port=0 
  // or change it to --insecure-port=<WHATERER_YOUR_LIKE>
  $ mv ../kube-apiserver.yaml kube-apiserver.yaml
  ```
- Do it right at startup. You need a kubeadm config file to do this. A simple one would like:

  ```
  apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1
  kind: MasterConfiguration
  apiServerExtraArgs:
    insecure-port: 8080 //or whatever you like

  // Then you can start a master node use `kubeadm init --config=<this-configure-file-path>`
  ```

Comment: @Crazykew - At first I didn't understand but now yes. If I comment this line `--insecure-port=0` and restart kubelet service so I can see open unsecured port  8080 and don't need _admin.conf_ in home dir. Thx for explanation.

Comment: @waldauf FYI, when you use *admin.conf*, actually you are trying to connect a secure-port defined in *admin.conf*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I've found the problem to be that the containers for API server etc, not starting.

I've found for me its a docker unix sock permission issue:

```
$ chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

this resolved the issue for me