# Installing Kubernetes on Virtual box with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I am trying to install Kubernetes on Ubuntu 16.04 VM, I tried this https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/, but the API server does not start.

The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Is there a good procedure on how to install Kubernetes on Ubuntu VM

Comment: I haven't tried on ubuntu. you can try with coreos. Here is the steps. http://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/vagrant/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably haven't set up the credentials for `kubectl`.

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/ && sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf; if ! fgrep -q KUBECONFIG= $HOME/.bashrc; then echo 'export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf' >> $HOME/.bashrc; fi;. $HOME/.bashrc
```

It takes `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` to the home directory and makes it readable by current user. Also adjusts `.bashrc` to set the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable to point to that `admin.conf`.

Comment: Where in the documentation did you get this information from?

Comment: @naisanza, I've learned it from the `kubeadm` utility. It does this during the initialization, and also prints something about these things to the console. But there is a documentation page that mentions KUBECONFIG: [Configure Access to Multiple Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

Answer (score 0):

In current version of `kubeadm`(v1.6.1), insecure port of ApiServer is abandoned by default, you can verify this by checking api-server yaml file in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`, there is kube-apiserver parameter `--insecure-port=0`.

You can

- Correct this in a running cluster:

  ```
  $ mv kube-apiserver.yaml ../kube-apiserver.yaml
  // edit ../kube-apiserver.yaml to remove --insecure-port=0 
  // or change it to --insecure-port=<WHATERER_YOUR_LIKE>
  $ mv ../kube-apiserver.yaml kube-apiserver.yaml
  ```
- Do it right at startup. You need a kubeadm config file to do this. A simple one would like:

  ```
  apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1
  kind: MasterConfiguration
  apiServerExtraArgs:
    insecure-port: 8080 //or whatever you like

  // Then you can start a master node use `kubeadm init --config=<this-configure-file-path>`
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to set up kubernetes on Ubuntu VM on Windows host using Oracle VM VirtualBox. See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032.

I switched to VMWare Workstation 12 (free not Pro) to use Kubernetes. Taking backups has gotten more tedious as exporting to ovf is available only with Pro. Kubernetes works fine