# k8s (single-node) not working after restart

Tags: kubernetes

I installed kubernetes on Ubuntu 16.04 (Virtualbox vm) - a single node with master tainted. It worked well. But after I restart my vm, it is not working any more.

kubectl commands are not working any more, throws this error -
The connection to the server localhost:8001 was refused - did you specify the
right host or port?

It looks similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603545/kubernetes-does-not-start-after-restart-system-ubuntu), but the solution is not working for me.

When I try "sudo docker ps -a", all kube pods are showing in Exited status.

Any helps/pointers, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the output of `systemctl status kubelet.service`

Comment: Hi Javier, here is the output - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CdBzOAck8TFj27MxwjslNbCtIlAxsziN

Comment: Dear experts, I am still unable to up this cluster. Has anyone faced it before? Any pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with my rancher 2 setup. I have two nodes in one cluster. One of my node servers was restarted and never connected to my cluster. Even though docker and containers were running fine.

One of the things i tried was reduce the number of workloads that can run in one node. I had increased it to 400. SO i put it back to 100. That's when I got my first breakthrough of what could be happening with my downed node. I go the error  "Path /var/lib/docker is mounted on / but it is not a shared or slave mount." A quick search led me to a similar issue in the [rancher github page](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/12205). Basically a [workaround by superseb](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/12205#issuecomment-385661588) fixed my issue. I sshed into my node and ran

```
> mount --make-rshared /
> docker start kubelet
```

Maybe your issue might be different, but maybe you could be having this same shared problem.