# Kubernetes master node is down after restarting host machine

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed a Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm. It works fine. But accidentally I restarted my host machine where master was up. After the  restart the kubelet was not running . I had to do

> Kubeadm reset

And

> Kubeadm init

What should I do to bring my cluster up automatically after a host machine restart ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes does not start after restart system (Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603545/kubernetes-does-not-start-after-restart-system-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to do `kubeadm reset` and `kubeadm init` in such cases.
To start `kubelet` service during the current session use:

```
systemctl start kubelet
```

To start service automatically during the boot, you must enable it using:

```
systemctl enable kubelet
```

Keep in mind that if you are running above commands as a non-root user, you will have to use `sudo`.

Comment: Hi I restarted my master node and then ran systemctl start kubelet . But it didn't start .  It was throwing main process exited error . I had to do kubeadm init .

Comment: Provide all actions you have done during clean cluster installation and log you have related to kubelet before and after restart.

Comment: For what its worth, in my case the issue was that swap got enabled after restart. `kubelet` was refusing to start because of that. Once I disabled swap using `swapoff -a`, `kubelet` was able to start successfully.